# Change the color of tmux pane indicators shown when using "display-pane"

Tags: linux, colors, tmux

When issuing a command like the following `bind Left select-pane -L \; display-pane` tmux will display numbers on every pane. The number shown on the active pane will have a different color than the rest.
Is it possible to change the colors of these numbers?
As a sidequestion, is it possible to change the duration of how long the numbers are displayed?

Comment: Instead of doing this by binding to the arrow keys, it makes more sense to do something like this: `set-hook -g pane-focus-in 'display-pane -d 750'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command "display-panes" will display numbers on every pane.
to change colours add those to your .tmux.conf

```
set display-panes-colour "white"
set display-panes-active-colour "black"
```

to change duration (in milliseconds) you have to use -d

```
bind Left select-pane -L \; display-pane -d 5000
```